# Python flask game not initializing

Tags: python, flask, pygame

I have my flask file and a seperate file which contains a pygame. Both work seperately, How would i combine the flask so that when i press my link on my webpage it starts running the external file, how would I call it?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import going
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/my-link/')
def my_link():
   return going.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug=True)
```

At the moment I am trying to run the main() method to initialize the program.

```
import pygame
##1100 * 800
size = [1100, 800]
score1 = 0
score2 = 0
blue = (100, 149, 237)
black = (0, 0, 0)
brown = (165,42,42)
white = (255, 255, 255)
green =(0,100,0)
red = (255,0,0)
dark_red = (200,0,0)
grey = (100,100,100)
other_grey = (0,0,100)
background = 'Mahogany.jpg'
pass_count = 0
player = 1
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Player(object):
    def ___init__(self,id):
        self.id = 1
    def quitGame(self):
        pygame.quit()
        quit()
    def pass_turn(self):
        global pass_count
        pass_count += 1
        if pass_count == 2:
            quitGame()      
    def score(player_text, score):
        return player_text + str(score) 


class Stone(object):
    def __init__(self,board,position,color):
        self.board = board
        self.position = position
        self.color = color
        self.placeStone()
    def placeStone(self):
        coords = (self.position[0] * 50,  self.position[1] * 50)
        pygame.draw.circle(self.board,self.color,coords,20,0)

        pygame.display.update()

class Board(object):    
    def draw_board(self):
        for i in range(12):
                for j in range(12):
                    rect = pygame.Rect(55 + (50 * i), 100 + (50 * j), 50, 50)
                    pygame.draw.rect(background, blue, rect, 1)
        screen.blit(background, (0,0))
        pygame.display.update()

    def text_objects(self,text, font):
        textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)

        return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

    def button(self,msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action = None):
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, ac,(x,y,w,h))

            if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
                action()
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, ic,(x,y,w,h))

        smallText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",20)
        textSurf, textRect = self.text_objects(msg, smallText)
        textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
        screen.blit(textSurf, textRect)
    def game_intro(self):

        intro = True
        while intro:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()

            screen.blit(background, (0,0))
            largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",60)
            TextSurf, TextRect = self.text_objects("GONLINE", largeText)
            TextRect.center = ((1100/2),(800/2))
            screen.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

            self.button("Play!",200,500,100,100,grey,other_grey,self.play_game)
            self.button("Quit!",700,500,100,100,red,dark_red,Player.quitGame)

            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(15)
    def play_game(self):
        width = 20
        height = 20 
        space_between = 5 

        global player
        finish = False
        self.draw_board()
        while not finish:


            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  
                    finish = True  
                elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and player == 1:
                    position = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                    if (event.button == 1) and (position[0] > 55 and position[0] < 710) and (position[1] > 100 and position[1] < 750):
                        x = int(round(((position[0]) / 50.0), 0))
                        y = int(round(((position[1]) / 50.0), 0))
                        Stone(screen,(x,y),white)

                        player = 2
                elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and player == 2:
                    position = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                    if (event.button == 1) and(position[0] > 55 and position[0] < 710) and (position[1] > 100 and position[1] < 750):
                        x = int(round(((position[0]) / 50.0), 0))
                        y = int(round(((position[1] ) / 50.0), 0))
                        Stone(screen,(x,y),black)

                        player = 1




            clock.tick(60)
            self.button("Pass!",750,200,100,100,grey,other_grey,Player.pass_turn)
            self.button("Quit!",950,200,100,100,red,dark_red,Player.quitGame)
            self.button(score("Player 1: ", score1),750,400,300,110,white,white)
            self.button(score("Player 2: ",score2),750,600,300,110,white, white)
            pygame.display.update()


        pygame.quit()

def main():
    player = Player()
    board = Board()
    board.game_intro()  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size, 0, 32) 
    pygame.display.set_caption("Go_Online")
    background = pygame.image.load(background).convert()
    main()
```

Here is the main game file

Comment: what happens currently?

Comment: pygame.error: video system not initialized

Comment: Running the game separately works perfect.

Comment: Can you show how you run it that works perfectly? Also the contents of `going` might help.

Comment: Could I send it to you privately its a college assignment I dont want to publish it

Comment: The purpose of this site is for public QA so that solutions to your problems might help others who come across the same thing. People aren't really here to help with your code for free.

Comment: I updated it there

Comment: BTW: as for me you could make it more OOP - keep `main()` (with `pygame.init()`) inside `Board()` and create class `Button`. Outside classes you could keep only constant values.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the two ways you try to call your game are slightly different.

The successful way, which seems to be something like 
`$ python going.py`

runs this code

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size, 0, 32) 
    pygame.display.set_caption("Go_Online")
    background = pygame.image.load(background).convert()
    main()
```

The flask route, when triggered runs this

```
return going.main()
```

You're missing some setup. My guess is that the bottom of your `going.py` should look like this.

```
def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size, 0, 32) 
    pygame.display.set_caption("Go_Online")
    background = pygame.image.load(background).convert()
    player = Player()
    board = Board()
    board.game_intro()  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: unfortunately i get the same error.

pygame.error: video system not initialized

Comment: I messed up the order but fixed it. Also, follow your stack trace whenever you get an error. There is a lot of helpful information there.

Comment: Thank you, the window launches now, only one small problem
"UnboundLocalError: local variable 'background' referenced before assignment"

I tried changing the ordering about but that doesnt work

Comment: When I change the name of the background variable, it turns to this error: NameError: name 'screen' is not defined

Comment: Now `screen` is local variable created inside `main()` and not available in other functions. You will have to use `global screen` in `main()` to make it again available in other functions. The same problem can be with other variables created in `main()`.